# All the possible combinations from the decomposition of the elements from an array

Tags: c, recursion, tree, recurrence

For example, if i have this array: {2,3,1} the first element can be decompose in {0,1,2}, the second one in {0,1,2,3} and the third one in {0,1}. So i have to make the sum of every single combination what is possible to be make.

```
example:

0,1,0
0,0,0
0,3,1
2,3,1
.....
```

My idea to above this problem is make a kind of tree like this.

```
        0                 1                2
  |   |   |   |     |   |   |   |    |   |   |   |
  0   1   2   3     0   1   2   3    0   1   2   3
 | | | | | | | |   | | | | | | | |  | | | | | | | |
 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

so my idea is make a Recursive function to make the sum:

```
1) move from top to bottom and when i find the limit change the move.
2) move from left to right, and when i find the limit in the right i return.
3) go back and move to the right, and back to the first step.
```

This is my code:

```
void tree(int*A, int i,int n,int j,int mov){
    if(mov){ ///move from up to bottom.
        if(i==n){ ///n is the large of the array.
           return; ///
           tree(A,i-1,n,j+1,0);
        }
        tree(A,i+1,n,j,1);
    }
    else{ ///move from left to right.
        if(j>A[i]){ ///j is decomposition of the element.
            return;
        }
        tree(A,i,n,j+1,0);
    }
}
```

I don't make any sum, I'm just trying to go over all the possible combination. But it's not working. I think is a problem whit what is being returning when the function find a limit.

I really want to solve it by myself but I'm in a dead point right now, maybe a need to know something else about recursive functions, so please don't put a complete solution, i want to learn by my way. I just want tips about what can i do. Is this the best way to solve this problem?

Also, please tell if the problem it's clear, my English is basic so i have problems to express what i want.

Comment: What would be your initial call to start the recursion?

Comment: @ChristophFreundl you mean the call of the function in the main?

Comment: Yes, I mean that one. I am still not sure whether I have fully understood the question but seeing the initial call should help.

Comment: @ChristophFreundl never mind, i solved it by myself making a new recursive function, thank you anyways :)